# Better way to retrieve the Count of records

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am dealing with a small-scale website that has tags to identify the genre of the topic. Every tag has followers similar to SO. When a tag is being entered, suggestions will populate which shows the auto-completed tags along with its followers.

What is the best way to design table for these tags so as to ease the retrieval follower-count and also to manage the tags.

```
1. 'tags'(
   id INT,
   tagname STRING)

   tag_followers(  
   tag_id INT,
   userid INT)
```

FollowersCount Query :

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tag_followers WHERE tag_id = (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tagname = "Games")
```

.......

```
2. 'tags'(
   id INT,
   tagname STRING,
   follower_count INT)

   tag_followers(  
   tag_id INT,
   userid INT)
```

FollowersCount Query :

```
SELECT  follower_count FROM tags WHERE tagname = "Games"
```

I had these two ideas. But I can't judge which would help me in fast retrieval on a long run. Please help me choose. Also, if there is better way than the above two, please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest your first approach and the query should be like:

> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tag_followers TF JOIN tags T on TF.tag_id = T.id and
>   tagname = "Games"

If you need count only then don't use count(*), just use count(1). Because count(*) will consider all columns while count(1) will consider only one column(first column) while calculating the count.

Steps needed in the second approach:

1. First you need to select follower_count from tags table
2. Then you need to increment it and update the tags table And then you need to
3. Insert into tag_followers table.

But in the first approach only step 3 is needed.

Comment: I agree. But won't too many join operation burdens the dB.. say my website needs the follower count operation larger number of times than the add_follower operation

Comment: To overcome this scenario you can use caching at your business layer. There are lots of query chasing ways like memcache , hibernate etc. Basically in the cache you can maintain count corresponding to the tag and once any new addition comes, you can expire the cache. In this way db hits will be minimal.